# NPM failure 'http fetch 404'

Tags: node.js, npm, http-status-code-404, nexus, node-commander

I'm having a very weird issue with npm getRemoteTarball operation where certain depencency packages are not getting fetched from my nexus server. The url formation in the getRemoteTarball operation is getting modified to an incorrect path and is causing failures.

Eg:
19461 silly mapToRegistry uri http://nexusurl.nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npmjs-registry-org/@types%2fcommander
19462 verbose addRemoteTarball http://nexusurl.nexus:8081/nexus/c/content/repositories/npmjs-registry-org/@types/commander/-/commander-2.12.2.tgz not in flight; adding

The artifact in nexus is present under
http://nexusurl.nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npmjs-registry-org/commander

The .npmrc file correctly contains the npmjs-registry-org repository address as
http://nexusurl.nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npmjs-registry-org/

Could someone help out on the reason why such a change is happening and how might it can be fixed?

node v6.10.1
npm  v3.10.10

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any chance you have apache running in front of nexus? If so, you need to configure it to allow encoded slashes:  https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Run+Behind+a+Reverse+Proxy#RunBehindaReverseProxy-ApachehttpdwithnpmRepositories

Comment: Unfortunately no. I was wondering if there was a way I could suppress the %2f and @types at our end(npm) to resolve the issue. Something on the bash or os level perhaps?

Comment: The %2f is an encoded slash character, it's being sent by npm (npm does this when requesting scoped packages).  Nexus will handle it just fine unless it's an older version of Nexus 2.x, in which case it won't work.

Comment: Yes the enterprise Nexus in our organization is a 2.x version. Hence the issue. Any possibility that the url can be altered to remove %2f and @types? Both seem to be causing an issue at Nexus.

Comment: What version specifically? Support for scoped npm packages was added in version 2.14.4.  If it's older than that you need to upgrade.

Comment: node v6.10.1 npm v3.10.10